# bigquery standar sql - Join table a if match found else table b

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a base table XYZ with below columns:

**idCustomer , idDevice , date , visit_time**

I have 2 other tables A and B (identical) with columns as below :

**idCustomer , idDevice , date , visit_time,channel_name,medium_name**

I want to join XYZ with A and B on columns: **idCustomer , idDevice & visit_time**

to get the columns : **channel_name,medium_name** (from either A or B)

This is the tricky part i have struggled with.

I want to get the **channel_name,medium_name** from table A if

**XYZ.idCustomer = A.idCustomer and XYZ.visit_time = A.visit_time**
for any given **idCustomer**

If there is no match then i want to fetch **channel_name,medium_name**  from B

if **XYZ.idDevice = B.idDevice and XYZ.visit_time = B.visit_time**

Thats the best i could explain . Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t.idCustomer, 
  t.idDevice, 
  t.visit_time, 
  CASE 
    WHEN NOT a.idCustomer IS NULL THEN a.channel_name
    WHEN NOT b.idDevice IS NULL THEN b.channel_name
  END channel_name,
  CASE 
    WHEN NOT a.idCustomer IS NULL THEN a.medium_name
    WHEN NOT b.idDevice IS NULL THEN b.medium_name
  END medium_name
FROM `project.dataset.XYZ` t
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.A` a
ON t.idCustomer = a.idCustomer AND t.visit_time = a.visit_time
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.B` b
ON t.idDevice = b.idDevice AND t.visit_time = b.visit_time
```

Another version of above (depends of quality of data - see Note at the bottom)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t.idCustomer, 
  t.idDevice, 
  t.visit_time, 
  COALESCE(a.channel_name, b.channel_name) channel_name,
  COALESCE(a.medium_name, b.medium_name) medium_name,
FROM `project.dataset.XYZ` t
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.A` a
ON t.idCustomer = a.idCustomer AND t.visit_time = a.visit_time
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.B` b
ON t.idDevice = b.idDevice AND t.visit_time = b.visit_time
```

Note: this (second) version will properly work if both columns channel_name and medium_name are not NULL in respective matched table  - otherwise it can end up with having one field from A and another from B - so first version is to go with